# Design Pattern: uniform interface for partially supported derived classes

Tags: c++, design-patterns, virtual, architecture

I am designing an interface for my project and curious if the idea can come true or not.
Here is the situation,
At run time, I want to use an array of base class pointers to issue commands to different derived objects.  Different derived objects got different implementation (virtual functions).  My problem is: if those objects got different different support level of the interface, how can I avoid writing an empty function?

For example, (my current code)

```
Class Base { //this is the main interface
public:
   virtual void basicFun() = 0;
   virtual void funA(int input1) {return;}
   virtual void funB(int input2) {return;}
   virtual void funC(int input3) {return;}
}

Class Derived1 : public Base { //this class support only funA()
public:
   void basicFun() {//....}
   void funA(int input1) {//do something}
}

Class Derived2 : public Base { //this class support both funA() funB()
public:
   void basicFun() {//....}
   void funA(int input1) {//do something}
   void funB(int input2) {//do something}
}

Class Derived3 : public Base { //this class support all
public:
   void basicFun() {//....}
   void funA(int input1) {//do something}
   void funB(int input2) {//do something}
   void funC(int input3) {//do something}
}
```

Assumption: for a certain object, unsupported function would never be called. i.e. BasePtr->funC() will never be called if the object pointed by basePtr is Derived1 or Derived2.
The problem is:

1. I must define an empty function either in Base or Derived if an uniform interface is desired
2. If empty functions are defined like above, compiler keeps warning me unreferenced parameters (input1~input3).  Of course I can turn it off, but just don't like this way.

So, is there any pattern that I can use to achieve an uniform interface without defining empty functions?  I have been thinking about this for a few days.  It seems impossible.  Because funA() funB() and funC() must be in the interface so that I can use a Base pointer array to control all objects, which means in Derived1, funB() and funC() must somehow be defined.

Thanks, and happy thanksgiving, and thanks for sharing your ideas.

Solti

Answer (score 1):

Uniform interfaces are a good thing. Which means that you must implement all methods in an interface, even if it means you will have empty methods. There is no design pattern for this problem, because it's not a real problem in the first place.

Think about this for a moment: say you have a `Car` interface, with methods `Accelerate()` and `Brake()`. A class that derives from `Car` must implement all methods. Would you want an object derived from `Car` implement the `Accelerate()` method but not the `Brake()` method? It would be an amazingly unsafe `Car`!

An interface in the context of OOP must have a well defined contract that is adhered to by both sides. In C++, this is enforced to a certain extent by requiring all pure virtuals to be implemented in derived class(es). Trying to instantiate a class with unimplemented virtual methods result in compilation error(s), assuming one doesn't use stupid tricks to get around it.

You object to creating empty methods because they cause compiler warnings. In your case, just omit the parameter name:

```
void funC(int) // Note lack of parameter name
{
}
```

Or comment the name out:

```
void funC(int /*input3*/)
{
}
```

Or even [by using templates!](http://herbsutter.com/2009/10/18/mailbag-shutting-up-compiler-warnings/)

```
template<class T> void ignore( const T& ) { }

//...

void funC(int input3)
{
    ignore(input3);
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. I can understand what you mean by a car without Brake(). However, if we are developing some kind of OEM software, we might want to use the same library level code but different AP level code. So I kind of hope keeping interface unchanged and only modify some code in AP. So, for some clients I do want to give them a car without Brake(). and it is guaranteed car->Brake() is never needed. (Maybe the client is doing crash tests)                                                           Second, I did try the parameter name omitting trick, and it works!!!  thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would have done: create a helper base class with empty default implementations of all pure virtual methods. Then you can derive from this base class instead of the main interface and then select which method to override.

```
// main interface, everything pure virtual
struct IBase
{
   virtual ~IBase() {}
   virtual void basicFun() = 0;
   virtual void funA(int input1) = 0;
   virtual void funB(int input2) = 0;
   virtual void funC(int input3) = 0;
};

// helper base class with default implementations (empty)
class Base : public IBase
{
   void basicFun() {}
   void funA(int input1) {}
   void funB(int input2) {}
   void funC(int input3) {}
};

class Derived1 : public Base { //this class support only funA()
   void funA(int input1) {//do something}
};

class Derived2 : public Base { //this class support both funA() funB()
   void funA(int input1) {//do something}
   void funB(int input2) {//do something}
};

class Derived3 : public IBase { //this class support all
   void basicFun() {//....}
   void funA(int input1) {//do something}
   void funB(int input2) {//do something}
   void funC(int input3) {//do something}
};

int main()
{
   // I always program to the interface
   IBase& b1 = Derived1(); b1.basicFun(); b1.funA(); b1.funB(); b1.funC();
   IBase& b2 = Derived2(); b2.basicFun(); b2.funA(); b2.funB(); b2.funC();
   IBase& b3 = Derived3(); b3.basicFun(); b3.funA(); b3.funB(); b3.funC();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you truly need non uniform interfaces (think about it before), maybe the Visitor pattern is worth a try:

```
struct Visitor;

struct Base
{
    virtual ~Base() {}
    virtual void accept(Visitor& v) { v.visit(*this); }
};

struct InterfaceA : Base
{
    void accept(Visitor& v) { v.visit(*this); }
    virtual void MethodA() = 0;
};

struct InterfaceB : Base
{
    void accept(Visitor& v) { v.visit(*this); }
    virtual void MethodB() = 0;
};

struct InterfaceA2 : InterfaceA
{
    void accept(Visitor& v) { v.visit(*this); }
    void MethodA(); // Override, eg. in terms of MethodC
    virtual void MethodC() = 0;
};

// Provide sensible default behavior. Note that the visitor class must be
// aware of the whole hierarchy of interfaces
struct Visitor
{
    virtual ~Visitor() {}
    virtual void visit(Base& b) { throw "not implemented"; }
    virtual void visit(InterfaceA& x) { this->visit(static_cast<Base&>(x)); }
    virtual void visit(InterfaceA2& x) { this->visit(static_cast<InterfaceA&>(x)); }
    virtual void visit(InterfaceB& x) { this->visit(static_cast<Base&>(x)); }
};


// Concrete visitor: you don't have to override all the functions. The unimplemented
// ones will default to what you expect.
struct MyAction : Visitor
{
    void visit(InterfaceA& x)
    {
        x.MethodA();
    }

    void visit(InterfaceB& x)
    {
        x.methodB();
    }
};
```

usage:

```
Base* x = getSomeConcreteObject();
MyAction f;
x->accept(f);
```

this will invoke either `MethodA` or `MethodB` depending on the runtime type of `x`. The visitor as implemented allows you not to overload many functions, and falls back to the action for a base class if the behavior is not implemented. Eventually, if you fail to provide an action in a visitor for some class, it will default to `throw "not implemented"`.

Const correctness may force you to distinguish between `Visitor` and `ConstVisitor`, for whom all the `accept` methods would be const.